npm install @yandex/ymaps3-vuefy - 404 Not Found
Делаю все по официальной документации (https://yandex.ru/dev/jsapi30/doc/ru/dg/concepts/integrations/vuefy)
и вообще, мне нужна яндекс карта, на которой можно ставить метки(маркеры) по клику мыши.
Пытаюсь сделать по доке пример, но ловлю ошибки. Вот мой код:
<script setup lang="ts">
import { ref } from 'vue'

const ymaps3Vue = await ymaps3.import('@yandex/ymaps3-vuefy');
const vuefy = ymaps3Vue.vuefy.bindTo(Vue);
const {YMap, YMapDefaultSchemeLayer, YMapDefaultFeaturesLayer, YMapMarker} = vuefy.module(ymaps3);

const location = ref(0)
</script>

<template>
<YMap :location="location">
    <YMapDefaultSchemeLayer />
    <YMapDefaultFeaturesLayer />
    <YMapMarker :coordinates="[34, 57]">
      <div class="marker marker_pill">I'm marker!</div>
    </YMapMarker>
  </YMap>
</template>

Webstorm подсвечивает мне "Vue: Cannot find name ymaps3. Did you mean YMap?"
При этом, не могу нормально заинсталить библиотеку эту @yandex/ymaps3-vuefy
ловлю ошибку в консоли:
npm install @yandex/ymaps3-vuefy
npm ERR! code E404
npm ERR! 404 Not Found - GET https://registry.npmjs.org/@yandex%2fymaps3-vuefy - Not found
npm ERR! 404 
npm ERR! 404  '@yandex/ymaps3-vuefy@*' is not in this registry.
npm ERR! 404 
npm ERR! 404 Note that you can also install from a
npm ERR! 404 tarball, folder, http url, or git url.    
npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:

Ребята, если кто работал - помогите, три дня мучаюсь с тем, чтоб простой пример с доки запустить, а если у кого то есть источник с реализацией карты с маркером - будет круто.

Здравствуйте!
Соберите, пожалуйста, полный пример ситуации и разместите его на JS Bin или CodeSandbox. Отправьте ссылку, чтобы можно было посмотреть, где возникает ошибка.
Могу также порекомендовать посмотреть страницу Создание стандартного маркера – это пример из документации готовой реализации карты с маркером на vue.js (чтобы получить код для Vue, нужно выбрать соответствующую опцию из меню под картой).
